# Stock Quantity on Shop Page

Tags: php, build

I would like to improve the following function. When it remain only 1 product in stock, I would like to been displayed a specific string.

```
function show_stock() {
global $product;
if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
if ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') < 3 ) { // if stock is low
echo '<div class="remaining">Μόνο ' . number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') . ' τεμάχια έμειναν!</div>';
}   else {
echo '<div class="remaining">' . number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') . ' τεμάχια στην αποθήκη</div>'; 
        }
    }else{
    echo '<div class="remaining">Εξαντλήθηκε!</div>';
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 20);


I would like to add one more "If" in the function above. For example:

if ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') = 1 ) { // if stock is low
echo '<div class="remaining">Μόνο ' . number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') . ' τεμάχιο έμεινε!</div>';
}
```

I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.